# how the ✅ emoji in email subject line is decoded to this? =?utf-8?B?4pyF?=

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8, html-email, emoji

Either using unicode or html won't work in the subject line, but this did: `=?utf-8?B?4pyF?=` I tried to look for a unicode to utf-8 decoder but none is returning anything like it.

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2047

Comment: And what programming language do you intend to use to decode this?

Comment: Converting "✅" to "=?utf-8?B?4pyF?=" is called encoding not decoding.

Answer (score 1):

The subject is encoded per [RFC2047](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2047.html).  In a netshell, an *encoded word* is:

```
encoded-word = "=?" charset "?" encoding "?" encoded-text "?="
```

*charset* is `utf-8`, *encoding* is `B` (per spec Base64 encoding), and *encoded-text* is `4pyF`.

With Python we can generate and verify this:

```py
>>> from email.header import Header
>>> h = Header('✅','utf-8')
>>> h.encode()
'=?utf-8?b?4pyF?='
```

```py
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64decode(b'4pyF').decode('utf-8')
'✅'
```